# Header background padding not changing in @media

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm fairly new to the world of scripts and coding, so I do not know the best terms to use.

I am trying to make a somewhat simple website, and I want my header background to have `padding-bottom` 120px at `min-width` 600px, and 0 at 1050. However, the padding-bottom only updates when changed in the properties for header.

Here is my code:

```
header {
   border-radius: 5px;
   display: block;
   width: auto;
   min-height: 200px;
   background: #E44;
   padding-top: 40px;
   padding-left: 38px;
   padding-right: 38px;
   padding-bottom: 136px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
 .header {
   padding-bottom:120px
 }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1050px) {
 .header {
   padding-bottom: 0px;
 }
}
```

The `padding-bottom` stays at 136px no matter the `min-width` of the window.

Comment: Because you are using ".header" instead of "header". The first set of property says its for "header".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you know the difference the dot does. `.header` is selection the header class. While `header` selects the element. Your code works fine, as you can see here, I'm using the media queries to change the background color instead of padding, just to make the point clear.

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tg3Len97/)

```css
header {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: #E44;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 38px;
  padding-right: 38px;
  padding-bottom: 136px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .header {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1050px) {
  .header {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a small typo here. You have an additional `dot(.)` which will mean a `class selector` as against the other style which is on `element selector`.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  header {
    padding-bottom:120px
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1050px) {
  header {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
}
```